# zstyle: changing the description style value of a tag

Tags: zsh-completion

I use the following zstyle commands to group completion items by their description:

```bash
zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:descriptions' format '%F{green}-- %d --%f'
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''

zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*:users' users alice bob eve
zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*:hosts' hosts lenovo hp asus
```

Which, for the ssh command, display something like this:

```bash
$ ssh <TAB>
-- remote host name --
asus    hp      lenovo
-- login name --
alice   bob     eve
```

My question: how can I change the descriptions for the tags *users* and *hosts*? That is, to replace "remote host name" by something like "hosts" and "login name" by "users".

I have tried the following, but it has no effect:

```bash
zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*:hosts' group-name 'hosts'
zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*:hosts' description 'hosts'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still trying to grok `zstyle` myself, so take what I'm saying with a bit of salt.

First of all, this seems to work, but I don't think it's quite correct:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*:users' users alice bob eve
zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*:hosts' hosts lenovo hp asus
```

`zstyle` itself has helpful completion which you can use to figure out which field has which purpose. This is telling me:

```
host ~ # zstyle ':completion:
completion widget
all-matches        complete-tag       expand-alias-word  history-words
complete-debug     correct-word       expand-word

host ~ # zstyle ':completion:*:
completer
approximate  correct      history      list         menu         prefix
complete     expand       ignored      match        oldlist

host ~ # zstyle ':completion:*:*:
external command
[                                              klockstat-bpfcc
7z                                             kmod
7za                                            lap
[...]

host ~ # zstyle ':completion:*:*:ssh:
argument

host ~ # zstyle ':completion:*:*:ssh:*:
tag
accounts           devices            interfaces         nicknames          sessions
all-expansions     directories        jobs               options            signals
all-files          directory-stack    keymaps            original           strings
[...]

host ~ # zstyle ':completion:*:*:ssh:*:users'                                         
style
accept-exact              filter                    max-exports               sort
accept-exact-dirs         force-list                max-matches-width         special-dirs
[...]
```

So with `zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*:users'`, you're accidentally giving `ssh` as completer, `*` as external command and `hosts` as argument. I can't quite figure out why it works nonetheless, but I believe this would be more correct, and still works for me:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:ssh:*:users' users alice bob eve
zstyle ':completion:*:*:ssh:*:hosts' hosts lenovo hp asus
```

Further on, I don't think that these two do what you expect:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*:hosts' group-name 'hosts'
zstyle ':completion:*:ssh:*:hosts' description 'hosts'
```

From what I can tell from `man zshcompsys`, `group-name` is used to group or ungroup several different tags (ie. if you wanted to configure whether users and hosts should be grouped together or not). `description` isn't completed by `zstyle` and isn't documented in the manpage, so I guess you've made that up :)

What I think you actually want, is, funnily enough... `format`, which you've already set here globally:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:descriptions' format '%F{green}-- %d --%f'
```

The `%d` is replaced with the descriptions given by the tags. So to get your custom descriptions, simply set different formats for your `users`/`hosts` tags, and replace `%d` with the description you want:

```
zstyle ':completion:*:*:ssh:*:users' format '%F{green}-- users --%f'
zstyle ':completion:*:*:ssh:*:hosts' format '%F{green}-- hosts --%f'
```

This works for me:

```
host ~ # ssh
-- hosts --
asus    hp      lenovo
-- users --
alice   bob     eve
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! Indeed, I wasn't that far :D. Regarding the first part of your answer, IIRC, you can group any number of consecutive `*` by just a single one, i.e. `:*:*:` -> `:*:`, this is why it works.